# Web.config TransformXML IIS Express Debug

Tags: asp.net, iis, visual-studio-2013, iis-express

Does anyone understand Microsoft's idea of TransformXML and running a WebApp with transformed Web.config in Debug mode?!

It's simply so that IIS Express does not pick up transformed (TransformXML in PostBuild) Web.config files from the bin/ folder.

I have tried to copy my transformed Web.config (PostBuild):

```
Web.config => bin/Web.config
Web.config => bin/<AssemblyName>.dll.config
```

without success.

- I have tried to create temporary files that are imported by "configSource" but they are not copied if not enlisted in the project.
- I don't want to have my debug settings as default settings in the project (I'm reusing the transformations for App.config in WebJobs- and Integration tests projects in the same solution).
- The proposed solutions of overwriting Web.config in the source folder are just not right.

Simply said: I just want the Web.config to be transformed and take it for a spin by hitting F5. That's it.

Does anyone know how to make IIS Express read the transformed bin/Web.config file when starting a Webapp in debug mode by hiting F5? Anyone knowing of any hidden tweaks for IIS Express to make it work the correct way?

Thanks for any solution on this.

Microsoft would be out of business by the end of the year if developers were able to bill them for all those lost hours of trying to get their non-scriptable non-logical solutions to work in reality.